# SOSL issue- Ranking of results set

Tags: sosl

We're using SOSL to search Account and Contact objects and facing an issue.
Records are returned in a variable of type `List<List<sobject>>` say **searchList**

I'm using this variable(**searchList**), to find specifically just Account records using following code :

```
  Account[] searchAccounts =  (Account[])searchList[0];
                    for(Account a :searchAccounts ){
                         accountIdsIni.add(a.id);
                    }
 System.debug('AccountIdsInitial='+accountIdsIni );
```

Now I print both **searchList** and **searchAccounts** variables. I'm finding Account records are returned in different **order**(sort) as shown below:
[image]

If you see, record(as highlighted in yellow) in debug log come **first** in SOSL variable but same record came on **4th number**, when I separately printed the list of Accounts listed.

Please suggest if this is an expected behavior !!

Comment: What is the type of `accountIdsIni`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming based on the observed behavior that `accountIdsIni` is typed as a `Set<Id>`. A [Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm) is

> an unordered collection of elements

The [iteration order](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) of a set

> is deterministic, so you can rely on the order being the same in each subsequent execution of the same code.

but that doesn't mean that it's defined to be *any specific order*, or that the order of elements printed by `System.debug()` is guaranteed to be the same as the iteration order.

If you want an ordered collection, use a `List`.

Comment: Thanks David. 'accountIdsIni'  is of type Account[] as shown in above code snippet . Let me try with list and revert.. thanks again !!

Comment: @curious_techy I think something is confused here. You're adding values of type `Id` to `accountIdsIni`, so it can't be of type `Account[]`.

Comment: Good Catch. Sorry.  accountIdsIni is of type Set and that was causing problem. Once i change it to 'List'. things worked fine. Thanks for your excellent support!!